# Storing Objects of an array into CSV file and reading them with specific arguments for GUI

Tags: java, arrays, swing, csv, arraylist

As a part of my assignment I had to store objects of an array in a flat-file and retrieve them when certain criteria was met. I can save the objects fine but when retrieving them I have an issue with getting more than one value, I understand what is going wrong but I am struggling to find a solution. Here is the concept of whats happening.

Button no 10,A (R1S10 in the code)is my testing button, When I click it it creates an event that I will show below.

[image: This is my system, its a ticket booking system]
Click event for button 10A -

```
private void R1S10ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      

    seats.add(seat1);


    if (R1S10.getBackground().equals(Color.red) &&(IsSeatBooked().equals("true"))){
        Component frame = null;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Seat UnBooked");
        seat1.setBooked("false");
        seat1.setName("");
        R1S10.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        try {
               reader();
            writer();

            //String booked = "true";
            //Pass String booked into csv file
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SeatingPlan.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    } 
    else{
        Component frame = null;
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Please enter name of Customer booking");
        if (name.isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "No value entered");

        } else if (name != null) {
            seat1.setName(name);
            seat1.setBooked("true");
            R1S10.setBackground(Color.red);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Your Booking has been placed");
            try {
                writer();
                reader();
                //String booked = "true";
                //Pass String booked into csv file
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SeatingPlan.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Followed by the screen below - 
[image: When 10A is first pressed]
Outcome -

[image: When booking is complete]

And when the button is pressed again -

[image: UnBooked]

I am using three methods in this SeatingPlan.java - writer(),reader() and IsSeatBooked().

SeatingPlan -

```
public class SeatingPlan extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form SeatingPlan
 */
String seatNo, name, bookedSeat;
FileWriter fileWriter = null;
List<Seat> seats = new ArrayList<Seat>();


//Seat Object Declaration

Seat seat1 = new Seat("R1S10","","false");
Seat seat2 = new Seat("R1S9", "", "false");
String fileName = "seat.csv";
```

writer -

```
 public void writer() throws IOException {
    //Delimiter used in CSV file
    final String NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR = "\n", COMMA_DELIMITER = ",";

    //CSV file header
    final String FILE_HEADER = "seatID,name,booked";

    //fileName = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/seat.csv";
    try {
        fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);

        //Write the CSV file header
        fileWriter.append(FILE_HEADER.toString());

        //Add a new line separator after the header
        fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);

        //Write a new student object list to the CSV file
        for (Seat seat : seats) {
            fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(seat.getSeatID()));
            fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
            fileWriter.append(seat.getName());
            fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
            fileWriter.append(seat.isBooked());
            fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);
        }

        System.out.println("CSV file was created successfully !!!");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in CsvFileWriter !!!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        fileWriter.flush();
        fileWriter.close();

    }
}
```

reader -

```
public void reader() {
    //Delimiter used in CSV file
    final String COMMA_DELIMITER = ",";
    //Student attributes index
    final int SEAT_ID_IDX = 0;
    final int SEAT_NAME_IDX = 1;
    final int SEAT_BOOKED = 2;
    //private static final int STUDENT_LNAME_IDX = 2;
    BufferedReader fileReader = null;

    try {

        //Create a new list of student to be filled by CSV file data 
        List<Seat> seats = new ArrayList<>();

        String line = "";

        //Create the file reader
        fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

        //Read the CSV file header to skip it
        fileReader.readLine();

        //Read the file line by line starting from the second line
        while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
            //Get all tokens available in line
            String[] tokens = line.split(COMMA_DELIMITER);
            if (tokens.length > 0) {
                //Create a new seat object and fill his  data
                Seat seat = new Seat(tokens[SEAT_ID_IDX],           
                tokens[SEAT_NAME_IDX], tokens[SEAT_BOOKED]);
                seats.add(seat);
                seatNo = tokens[SEAT_ID_IDX];
               //System.out.println("Seat Number: " + seatNo);
                bookedSeat = tokens[SEAT_BOOKED];
              }
        }

        //Print the new student list
        for (Seat seat : seats) {
            System.out.println(seat.toString());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in CsvFileReader !!!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fileReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error while closing fileReader !!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}//end reader
```

SeatingPlan - This if where I have tried to have the arguments controlling the outcome but IsBooked is colliding when multiple seats are selected.

```
 public SeatingPlan() throws IOException {
    setVisible(true);
    initComponents();
    //reader();
    ColourSectionGold();
    ColourSectionBronze();
    reader();

    if(R1S10.getBackground().equals(Color.yellow) && (IsSeatBooked().equals("true"))){ R1S10.setBackground(Color.red);}
    //if(R1S9.getBackground().equals(Color.yellow) && (IsSeatBooked().equals("true2"))){ R1S9.setBackground(Color.red);}
   }
```

IsSeatBooked -

```
 public String IsSeatBooked(){
 return bookedSeat;   
}//end IsSeatBooked
```

Im using the method above as my argument to see whether a seat is booked or not, but when a new seat is click it sets the whole value of 'bookedSeat' - which leaves the system not working correctly. I understand the code is not very efficient but is there any temporary fix for this problem, if I have explained it correctly.

Also I will include my class for Seat -

```
public class Seat {
private String seatID;
private String booked;
private String name;
private int price;

public Seat(String seatID,String name,String booked){
    this.seatID = seatID;
    this.booked = "";
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
}

public String getSeatID() {
    return seatID;
}

public void setSeatID(String seatID) {
    this.seatID = seatID;
}

public String isBooked() {
    return booked;
}

public void setBooked(String booked) {
   this.booked = booked;
}

public String getStatus(){
    return booked;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
} 

public void setPrice() {
   this.price = price;
}}//end class Seat
```

And a look at the CSV file that is created -

[image: CSV Outcome]

I wish to be able to click more than one button and save its state, Button 10 works fine at the moment, but as IsBooked only has one value at a time it clashes.

If you took the time to check this out, I appreciate it. Any constructive criticism is helpful and any ideas would be great!

Thanks,
Paddy.

Comment: If ever a question needed an [mcve], this is it. You will likely have a much greater chance of getting a decent answer if you can create and post a valid MCVE with your question -- this code would not have GUI code, since it appears that your ultimate question doesn't really involve the GUI but rather is more involved with storing and retrieving object state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too much code to look at to see exactly what you are doing.

Instead of using your csv file, you could create a `Properties` file. The `Properties`file will store the data in the form of:

```
key:data
```

So in your case the key would be the id: A1, A2... and the data would be the name of the person who booked the seat.

So the file would start out as empty. When you create the GUI you would create a loop that checks each id to see if an entry is found in the Properties field. If it is found then you display the seat as taken, otherwise it is empty.

Then whenever you want to book a seat you just use the `setProperty(...)` method.

The `Properties` class has `load(...)` and `store(...)` methods.

So the `Properties` class allows you to easily manage a flat file database with minimal effort.

Note, you would never have variable names like R1S10. That would requirement 100 different variables with if/else statements. Instead you would extend JButton and pass in the row and seat as parameters the button. Then in the ActionListener for the button you can access the row/seat information to built the ID used as the key for the properties file.

Edit:

> Couldn't quite make the loop that checks if the ID is in the properties file.

If the property is null, the seath is empty.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("A2", "Smith");
        properties.setProperty("C3", "Jones");

        String[] rows = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
        int seats = 4;

        for (int row = 0; row < rows.length; row++)
        {
            for (int seat = 1; seat <= seats; seat++)
            {
                String key = rows[row] + seat;
                String property = properties.getProperty( key );

                System.out.println(key + " : " + property);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response buddy! I'm going give this a try tonight. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Used the concept of this answer. Very useful! Couldn't quite make the loop that checks if the ID is in the properties file. But I got it working, I'll worry about the efficiency later! Thanks @camickr

Comment: Been playing around with the property file and cant find anything about checking the file to see if there's a certain number of values in it. For ex. 'if key.lenght = 10' - I want to be able to create an event when the file reaches 10 values. Could you share any insight? @camickr

Comment: @phpPaddy, `I want to be able to create an event when the file reaches 10 values.` - the file is just an external storage medium for the data. The `Properties` class has all the methods that you need. Basically the `Properties` class is just an extension of a `Hashtable` that provides permanents storage for the data in a `Hashtable`. So look at the method of the `Properties` class which will include the methods of the `Hashtable` class. Learning to read the API is required to do programming.